# Multicol Help formatting

Tags: formatting, multicol, multicolumn

I am trying to create a notesheet for a class of mine. However, for the love of god I cannot force my text to go into the next column. I am using the `multicol` package; I've tried using `\columnbreak` and `\newpage` commands, but they always cut off the stuff before the column break (as if I never wrote it).

I was wondering if someone could look at my code and suggest what I need to do?
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent

\begin{multicols}{3}

\textit{Riemann Integrals \& Properties}
\begin{align*}
    \mathscr{U}(\mathscr{P},f) &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}M_{i} \Delta x_{i} \\
    \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{P},f) &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}m_{i} \Delta x_{i} \\
    \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{P},f) &\leq \mathscr{U}(\mathscr{P},f) \\
    \overline{\int_{a}^{b}}f &= \text{inf}\{ \mathscr{U}(\mathscr{P},f)\} \\
    \underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f &= \text{sup}\{ \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{P},f)\} \\
\end{align*}

\begin{center}
  \hrule
\end{center}

If $\mathscr{P}^{*}$ is a refinement of $\mathscr{P}$,
then the following holds true:
\begin{align*}
    \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{P},f) &\leq \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{P}^{*},f) \\
    &\leq \mathscr{U}(\mathscr{P}^{*},f) \leq \mathscr{U}(\mathscr{P},f) \\
\end{align*}

\begin{center}
  \hrule
\end{center}

Let $f$ be a bounded real-value function on the closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$. If $\overline{\int_{a}^{b}}f = \underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f$, then $f \in \mathscr{R}[a,b]$.  $\overline{\int_{a}^{b}}f = -\underline{\int_{b}^{a}}f$ follows if $f \in \mathscr{R}[a,b] \\$.


Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $[a,b]$. If $f$ is continuous or monotone on $[a,b]$, then $f \in \mathscr{R}[a,b] \\$.


If $f \in \mathscr{R}[a,b]$, then it follows that  $|f|,f^{2} \in \mathscr{R}[a,b]. \\$.


Let $f$ be a bounded real-valued function on $[a,b]$, and suppose $a<c<b$. Then $f \in \mathscr{R}[a,b] \iff f \in \mathscr{R}[a,c]$ and $f \in \mathscr{R}[c,b]$. If so: $\int_{a}^{b}f=\int_{a}^{c}f + \int_{b}^{c}f. \\ \\$ 
\begin{center}
  \hrule
\end{center}
\begin{align*}
     & \text{Let} f,g \in \mathscr{R}[a,b]. \: \text{Then,} \\
     & a) \: f+g \in \mathscr{R}[a,b] \: with \int_{a}^{b}(f+g) = \int_{a}^{b}f+\int_{a}^{b}g  \\
     & b) \: cf \in \mathscr{R}[a,b] \: with \int_{a}^{b}cf = c\int_{a}^{b}f \\
     & c) \: fg \in \mathscr{R}[a,b] \\
     & d) \: |f|\in \mathscr{R}[a,b] \: with \left| \int_{a}^{b}f \right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f| \\
\end{align*}

\textit{F.T.C. I \& II}


\end{multicols*{3}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is an error. Need to change `\end{multicols*{3}}` to `\end{multicols}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the output on the console when you compile, you will find

```bash
! LaTeX Error: \begin{multicols} on input line 44 ended by \end{multicols*{3}}.


See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.94 \end{multicols*{3}}

?
```

That is, your text doesn't disappear at all. LaTeX refuses to compile the code and tells you what is wrong.

The solution is to replace

```
\end{multicols*{3}}
```

with

```
\end{multicols}
```

so that it matches the

```
\begin{multicols}
```

earlier. The `{3}` is an argument to the environment `multicols`, but only needs to be specified at the beginning. That is, the syntax is

```
\begin{multicols}{3}

...

\end{multicols}
```